# I cannot get asynchronous generators or iterators to actually run asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, iterator, generator

I am working with [BigQuery's Async Storage Write API](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquerystorage/latest/google.cloud.bigquery_storage_v1.services.big_query_write.BigQueryWriteAsyncClient#google_cloud_bigquery_storage_v1_services_big_query_write_BigQueryWriteAsyncClient_create_write_stream). It works extensively with *async generators and iterators*, with which I have no previous experience. I was unfortunately not getting any of the **async** aspect working.

I stepped back, to understand async generators better.  I am most comfortable with `trio`, but it seems that `trio`'s core `open_nursery` function does not work with generators. So I created the simplest generator I could, just to get my head around it:

```py
>>> import trio
>>> async def generator():
...   for i in range(10):
...     await trio.sleep(random.random())
...     yield i
... 
>>> async def main():
...   async for idx in generator():
...     print(idx)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>> trio.run(main)
```

This is exactly how it ran, in order. The length of the pause between printing numbers would change, but it was always running synchronously: the generator yielded a value only after awaiting, and the `async for` would only move to the next value after the previous yield was given.

This is not what I expected, nor what I need or hope for. I was expecting that all of the "jobs" would be triggered immediately, that all of the print statements would happen randomly out of order, and that the entire thing would take less than 1 second. (`random.random()` has a range between 0 and 1.)

---

How can I work with ***async generators and iterators*** in a way that is truly asynchronous, such that all of the tasks are scheduled as fast as possible, and they are run "in parallel"?

(I know that in fact I am only using one processor and one thread, but, for instance, `trio.sleep()` is supposed to provide a checkpoint to say that another task can be started because it is idle.)

Please provide a toy code example that, for instance, takes my generator and runs it in a truly parallel way.  And if there is a way to use `trio`'s nurseries with generators or iterators, please also show an example with that.

Comment: This is very much expected behavior for async generators - you probably want to check how normal generators start & stop, as you might have those understood in a bit wrong way!

Comment: Yes, I recognize that I understood it wrong.  But my point is:  how can I get things _queued_, so that they can run more efficiently.  As it is, I cannot see any purpose to an async generator, other than it is able to have `await`s and other `async`s in it.  It provides no boost in efficiency.  If that's the case, why would BigQuery, for instance, rely upon async iterators for all their I/O processing?  It doesn't make sense... unless there is something more to it.

Comment: And yes, I understand how normal generators work.  Unfortunately, the async `yield` is acting exactly identically to the normal `yield`, which means that it is providing no value-add, in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Ah now I wish I saw that earlier! Time to scrap my hour-long answer and rewrite again! Gimme more time and I'll try my best to explain it a bit(hopefully)

Comment: Honestly with normal-async diff of generator explanation part of answer gone, all it left might be "It can still let other asynchronous job do it's thing" which could be useful for you or not, depending on what you're writing - which isn't much of use as an answer

Comment: OK, understood.  That's what I was afraid of...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254776/discussion-between-jupiterbjy-and-mike-williamson).